# Consecutive (conditional) Where clauses in Linq

Tags: linq, sharepoint

I'm trying to construct a Linq statement to be used from a client with the Sharepoint (2010) object model.

This is the problematic piece of code:

```
var result = news.Where(n => (bool)n["Online"]
    && ((DateTime)n["StartDate"] <= DateTime.Now && (DateTime)n["StopDate"] >= DateTime.Now));

if (currentUser.IsAgUser())
    result = result.Where(n => (string)n["Role"] != "AG-ADMIN");

var filteredNews = sharepointContext.LoadQuery(result);
```

When the `if` parte is executed and so another `Where` is added to `result`, I get the followin error when `LoadQuery`ing it.

```
The query expression 'value(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection).Where(n => (Convert(n.get_Item("Online")) AndAlso ((Convert(n.get_Item("StartDate")) <= DateTime.Now) AndAlso (Convert(n.get_Item("StopDate")) >= DateTime.Now)))).Where(n => (Convert(n.get_Item("Role")) != "AG-ADMIN"))' is not supported.
```

Where is the error coming from? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like SharePoint doesn't support several wheres.

Cheap solution:

```
var result = currentUser.IsAgUser() 
                 ? news.Where(n => (bool)n["Online"]
&& ((DateTime)n["StartDate"] <= DateTime.Now && (DateTime)n["StopDate"] >= DateTime.Now) && (string)n["Role"] != "AG-ADMIN")
                 : news.Where(n => (bool)n["Online"]
&& ((DateTime)n["StartDate"] <= DateTime.Now && (DateTime)n["StopDate"] >= DateTime.Now)); 

var filteredNews = sharepointContext.LoadQuery(result);
```

Comment: You can manipulate the expression tree but it will be a really complex code and the query is not complicated.

Comment: I know I'm a little late. I have nearly the same issue. It look's like SharePoint doesn't support combining Linq Expressions with AndAlso and so on.